# What does this error mean?

Tags: php, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1

[Edit: following code picked out of a comment further down... indentation could be wrong]

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target_path = "images/";     
$target = $target_path . basename ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$did = $_POST['did']; 
$name = $_POST['dname']; 
$disc = $_POST['ddisc']; 
$price = $_POST['dprice']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$con = mysql_connect("","restoraunt","123456"); 
// àéôä ùí äùøú ùìê, localhost àå îùäå? 
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
mysql_select_db("restoraunt", $con); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO menu VALUES ('$did', '$name', '$disc', '$price','a','c','$pic')") ;
```

Comment: I means that You have an error in your SQL syntax; Please post your SQL query :)

Comment: I don't think you're going to get much help with your question as it is.  You really need to at the very least post your SQL and a description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are most probably sticking a query result resource into another SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're saying "near 'Resource id #2'" means that your SQL is actually the text **Resource id #2** which is not a valid SQL.

I figure that you are doing this: `mysql_query($someVariable)` The variable that you are passing is actually an object, not a string.

Comment: Actually, it's **not** an **object**, but a [PHP resource type](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). And that resource is typecasted when it is concatenated into the SQL string.

Comment: Sometimes I lie to the OP to explain things in easier terms.

Comment: it's not **easier terms**, it's **wrong terms**. Objects and Resources have fixed meaning in PHP. They are not the same things.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in you're sql query right before `Resource id #2` , mysql server can't iterpret it . Post the full query and we'll be able to tell you more about the error .

Comment: //This is the directory where images will be saved
$target_path = "images/";
$target = $target_path . basename ($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$did = $_POST['did'];
$name = $_POST['dname'];
$disc = $_POST['ddisc'];
$price = $_POST['dprice'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$con = mysql_connect("","restoraunt","123456"); // àéôä ùí äùøú ùìê, localhost àå îùäå?
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("restoraunt", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `menu` VALUES ('$did', '$name', '$disc', '$price','a','c','$pic')") ;

Comment: right before mysql_query... write `var_dump("INSERT INTO menu VALUES ('$did', '$name', '$disc', '$price','a','c','$pic')");die();` and post what you get , i can't understand anything from what you posted there .